# Reg: Error in stretched exponential function fitting

Tags: python, python-2.7, curve-fitting

I am having data in.csv file and it contains 2 column x and y axis. The axis are read from .csv file and then fitting the data with stretched exponential function but its showing error.

Here I am giving example data to easy understanding.

My function is `f(x) = a. exp (-b.t) ^ c + d`. (Stretched exponential fitting). I want to fit this data according to this function and I want the final value of a, b, c and d.

My coding is:

```
# Reading data
x=data[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
y=data[7.2489, 7.0123, 7.0006, 7.0003, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7]
# Fitting Streched Exponential Decay Curve
smoothx = np.linspace(x[0], x[-1], (5*x[-1]))
guess_a, guess_b, guess_c, guess_d = 4000, -0.005, 4, 4000
guess = [guess_a, guess_b, guess_c, guess_d]
f_theory1 = lambda t, a, b, c, d: a * np.exp((b*t)^(c)) + d
p, cov = curve_fit(f_theory1, x, y, p0=np.array(guess))
f_fit1 = lambda t: p[0] * np.exp((p[1] * t)^((p[2]))) + p[3]
plt.show()
```

Here I am showing only guess and fitting part of my program.

Kindly correct mistakes in my code for better fitting.

Comment: I'm not sure what data types you're using, but `^` is conventionally "bitwise XOR" in Python, rather than exponentiation. What happens if you replace them with `**`? Also, when you say "its showing error", what exactly is the error message?

Comment: Thanks kevin. I replaced ^ by **. After that i am getting this error

RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in power.

Comment: The error might result from the fact that you calculate roots from negative numbers. I corrected that and added an answer below; please let me know whether that solves your problem or whether the answer needs to be revised.

Comment: Thanks cleb. It also didnt works. The error was too many parameter inside  exponential. f_theory1 = lambda t, a, b, c, d: a * np.exp((b*t)^(c)) + d. so i changed formula to f_theory1 = lambda t, a, b, c, d: a * np.exp((b)(t)^(c)) + d. Then i am getting out of b^c, from that i calculated b value manually. Thanks once again to Kevin and cleb for your wonderful contribution,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [lmfit](http://cars9.uchicago.edu/software/python/lmfit/installation.html) to fit your parameters. Then the plot looks like this:

[image]

and the corresponding parameters are the following:

```
a:   56.8404075 
b:  -5.43686170 
c:   49.9888343 
d:   7.00146666
```

The advantage of `lmfit` is that you can also easily constrain the range of your parameters using the `min` and `max` argument (see code below).

Here is the code that produces the plot; please not that I slightly modified your model to avoid calculating roots from negative numbers:

```
from lmfit import minimize, Parameters, Parameter, report_fit
import numpy as np

x=np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]  )
y=np.array([7.2489, 7.0123, 7.0006, 7.0003, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7])  


def f_theory1(params, x, data):  
    a = params['a'].value
    b = params['b'].value
    c = params['c'].value
    d = params['d'].value

    model = a * np.exp(b*(x**c)) + d # now b can become negative; in your definition it could not

    return model - data #that's what you want to minimize

# create a set of Parameters
#'value' is the initial condition
#'min' and 'max' define your boundaries
params = Parameters()
params.add('a', value= 40, min=-10, max=10000) 
params.add('b', value= -0.005, min=-10, max=200)
params.add('c', value= .03, min=-10, max=400) 
params.add('d', value= 40.0, min=-10, max=400) 

# do fit, here with leastsq model
result = minimize(f_theory1, params, args=(x, y))

# calculate final result
final = y + result.residual

# write error report
report_fit(params)

#plot results
try:
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    plt.plot(x, y, 'k+')
    plt.plot(x, final, 'r')
    plt.ylim([6.95, 7.3])
    plt.show()
except:
    pass
```

Comment: @Vicknesh: Welcome. If it solved your problem, I would also appreciate if you accepted this answer by clicking on the small check next to my answer which then turns green. Thanks!